# Compress image on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I used to get an image from the frontend and store it in the backend.

How can I compress that image before storing it to the database?

Is there any gem for compressing an image?

or any other way to do that?

Comment: Most image formats are already compressed pretty well, and compress/decompress will affect performance - why do you want to compress the image further?

Comment: when user signup and upload a profile image,It beyond 2MB and it slow down my site

Comment: Then most probably, you don't want to compress it, but scale it to a lower resolution

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gem. It is a wrapper for ImageMagick, that lets you process uploaded files before storing them (e.g. resize, convert, optimize etc).